# Reference Path in VS2019 is not recognized

Tags: visual-studio

We are using the Nuget package for System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Client.2.0.5 in a C# project. In VS2017 this was working without any problems, but after switching to VS2019 it gives a compile error that it cannot find the package.

In the .csproj file the relative path for HintPath is correct and the dll's are in the correct folder under the packages directory:
packages\System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Client.2.0.5\lib\portable-net45+wp8+wpa81+win8+monoandroid+monotouch+Xamarin.iOS+Xamarin.Mac

When I change the path above manually to packages\System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Client.2.0.5\lib\net45 it works fine. This gives me the suspicion that for some reason VS2019 cannot resolve the original path.

Has anybody ran into the same issue and found a solution as I currently ran out of ideas.

Comment: That package doesn't have a "net45" directory, if you renamed it by hand then you ought to mention that.  Random guess: that directory name is pretty long.  Ensure that the full path of the file does not exceed the maximum path length, 259 characters.  Move the project closer to the root to avoid.

Comment: I know that it does not have a net45 directory. I just added it manually to see whether it would work and of course that is not a solution. As for the path, why would it work in VS2017 and not in VS2019?

Comment: We are having the exact same issue. Did you find a fix?

Comment: I think there is a minor bug in VS2019 - the priority of what path to look for first has been changed. Before it was solution -> Project Reference Paths -> Hintpath. I dont know what it's doing now. I'm referring internal projects and still getting 'Source file is different from when module was built' on debug.